# TextField Causing 'Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.' Flutter

Tags: flutter, textfield

I have a TextField that is causing the below error.  It is only triggered when I start typing inside the TextField.  I tried wrapping either the Sliverappbar or the TextField inside a Builder but same error is encountered.

======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following assertion was thrown while dispatching notifications for FocusManager:
Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.

At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.

To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
#0      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup. (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3906:9)
#1      Element._debugCheckStateIsActiveForAncestorLookup (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3920:6)
#2      Element.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3962:12)
#3      MediaQuery.of (package:flutter/src/widgets/media_query.dart:814:38)
#4      _InkResponseState._shouldShowFocus (package:flutter/src/material/ink_well.dart:925:44)
...
The FocusManager sending notification was: FocusManager#23a1d
primaryFocus: FocusNode#4875a([PRIMARY FOCUS])
primaryFocusCreator: EditableText-[LabeledGlobalKey#ccd2a] ← UnmanagedRestorationScope ← RepaintBoundary ← _Decorator ← InputDecorator ← AnimatedBuilder ← _PointerListener ← Listener ← RawGestureDetector ← TextSelectionGestureDetector ← Semantics ← AnimatedBuilder ← IgnorePointer ← _RawMouseRegion ← MouseRegion ← TextField ← ConstrainedBox ← Padding ← Container ← ColoredBox ← ⋯

Code below.

```
_showsearchfield
                    ? _bottombarisVisible
                    ? SliverAppBar(
                  backgroundColor: twhite,
                  leading: Container(),
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    titlePadding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
                    title: Container(
                      color: twhite,
                      //actual search box
                      child: Container(
                        height: screenheight*0.057,
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(
                            left: screenwidth*0.041,
                            right: screenwidth*0.041,
                            top: screenheight*0.027,
                            bottom: screenheight*0.032
                        ),
                        child: TextField(
                          style: MyTextStyle(16, tblack, FontWeight.w600),
                          controller: _mysearchwords,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0, ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide: BorderSide(width: 0, ),
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                            ),
                            suffixIcon: InkWell(
                              child:Icon(Icons.close,size: 20,color: tblack,),
                              splashColor: torangesplash,
                              onTap: _clearsearchtext,
                            ),
                            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 10),
                            hintText: 'Search',
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black87,fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                          ),
                          onSubmitted: (String value) async {
                            
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  floating: false,
                  pinned: true,
                )
                    : SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(),
                )
                    : SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Container(),
                ),
```

Comment: Would appreciate any help please.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same issue, a simple Flutter hot restart solved my issue fortunately

Comment: After two search hours, I found this answer. It's solved my problem for case TextFormField inside `showModalBottomSheet`. Thanks!